# Set proxy in Webpack production config Angular 2+

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, production-environment

As I can see, there is proxy in `webpack.dev.config`. How do I set proxy in `webpack.prod.config` ? I want to call another api domain url other than self domain url.

Comment: in production you won't use webpack-dev server with proxy. You need to configure proxy in your http server. For example if you http server is nginx, you can do something like   location /api/ {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova, I am using `jhipster` Source: https://jhipster.github.io/using-angular Can you show me any working example ?

Comment: JHipster is an application generator, so that does not answer the question of which server you are serving your production files. What kind of configuration did you generate with JHipster? Knowing what server you will serve your code with in a production setup is essential for helping you set up a proxy, unless you want to put a proxy in front of it.

Answer (score 4):

I going to try to provide somewhat of an answer.

As Julia points out. You should not be using the webpack dev server in your production environment as it is not meant for that, so the question should not be how to configure a production proxy config with it. That being said, if you really want to you can start a webpack server with custom proxy config like so:

```
ng serve --proxy-conf proxy.conf.json
```

What you should be doing is to use webpack, through the `angular/cli` to build a production build with and then move those files to be served by a static file server of your choosing. Build a production bundle like so:

```
ng build --prod
```

All above taken from your link https://jhipster.github.io/using-angular/

Since you are using JHipster there are already guides and tooling on how to take your code into production. Continue your reading here: https://jhipster.github.io/production/

I hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: Is `proxy` a good option or shall i go for environment variable ?

Comment: A proxy (reverse proxy) and environment variables are not tools that solve the same problem, so exactly what is it that you wish to accomplish? Do you want your client/fontend to speak to other webservices than your own or do you which to put a proxy in front of your servers so that you can direct incoming requests?

Comment: Yes, my front end server and backend (webservices) server are different.

Comment: Then I suggest that you use a reverse proxy in front of them. Such as https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/